# Using iteration in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a  following XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[child::node()
            [contains(@Source, 'filename1')
            or contains(@Source, 'filename2')]]" />
```

Can anybody advice me how I can use a parameter or variable instead of "filename1" and "filename2" to loop through filemanes?

How can the second template be rewritten (perhaps, with adding a new template?) to use an inline xsl, such as

```
  <xsl:variable name="FileName">
    <name>filename1</name>
    <name>filename2</name>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Thanks in advance,

Leo

Comment: You haven't shown your XML source, but I wonder if you really need contains() here? I ask because using contains() where "=" would do is a common mistake; and if that were the case, the answer would simply be `match="*[*/@Source = $FileName/name]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution** (this is easier to do with XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:fileNames>
   <f>filename1</f>
   <f>filename2</f>
 </my:fileNames>

 <xsl:variable name="vFilenames"
               select="document('')/*/my:fileNames/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity" priority="-1">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="vHit">
   <xsl:for-each select="$vFilenames">
    <xsl:if test=
     "$vCur/node()[contains(@Source, current())]">1</xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(string-length($vHit))">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (when will you, people, learn to provide your source XML???):

```
<t>
    <tt>
        <x>
            <y/>
        </x>
        <mm>
            <z Source="filename1">
                <u/>
                <v/>
            </z>
        </mm>
        <rr>
            <m Source="filename2">
                <u/>
                <v/>
            </m>
        </rr>
        <v-v>
            <p Source="filename3">
                <u/>
                <v/>
            </p>
        </v-v>
    </tt>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <tt>
      <x>
         <y/>
      </x>
      <v-v>
         <p Source="filename3">
            <u/>
            <v/>
         </p>
      </v-v>
   </tt>
</t>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pFileNames">
   <f>filename1</f>
   <f>filename2</f>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[node()
          [some $fn in $pFileNames/f
            satisfies
              contains(@Source, $fn)
          ]
         ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (as above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <tt>
      <x>
         <y/>
      </x>
      <v-v>
         <p Source="filename3">
            <u/>
            <v/>
         </p>
      </v-v>
   </tt>
</t>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your helpful recommendations and valuable suggestions. The sample XML file suits my needs. Currently I have to use XSLT 1.0; for this reason Michael's recommendation does not seem to be directly applicable to my task. Another limitation is that I can't use the document funciton; so I modifed Dimitres variable definition with <xsl:variable name="vFilenames" select="msxsl:node-set($Filenames)/name"/> I intentionally used contains() in my template; yet, using "=" in other cases may be important as well, so I would be very interested in the solution for this case too

Comment: Hello Dimitre, Of course, I would like to confirm accepting this answer. Do I have to make this confirmation somewhere on this web site? BTW, in my previous comment, I asked you and Michael for your recommendations on the template specification when using "=" instead of "contains". If you can outline a corresponding approach, it would be very helpful to me. Thanks and regatrds, Leo

Comment: @Leo68: Yes, accepting an answer is done by clicking the "check-mark" next to this answer. As for `contains()` vs `=`, the former is more lax and the latter stricter. `contains($String, $Pattern)` evaluates to `true()` exactly when `$String` *contains* the string `$Pattren` -- that is anywhere in `$String`. `=` on the other hand requires that `$String` be exactly equal (in string-length and character by character) to `$Pattern`. Two other functions similar to `contains()` exist: `starts-with()` and (in XPath 2.0) `ends-with()`. Use `contains()` when not sure where the pattern is in the string